# Release Build Issue in Android - Nativescript+ Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am having an issue while taking a release build in android:

I am having different html files for android and ios for two components. There is no issue while building or running in develop mode.. When I am trying to take a release build this possess as an issue and not able to take the build. Is there any solution for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are seeing in the console?

Comment: `ERROR in app/src/modules/home/components/newsfeed/newsfeed.component.ts(35,16): Error during template compileof 'NewsFeedComponent'
  Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced in decorators because the value of this variableis needed by the template compiler in 'isAndroid'
    'isAndroid' is not initialized at tns-core-modules/platform/platform.ts(11,12).`  @Manoj

Comment: Can you share a repo with sample code to reproduce the issue.